# How to send control signals using paramiko in python?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a code snippet something like this:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port=Port, username=usr,password=Psw)
stdin, stdout, stderr= ssh.exec_command("watch -n1 ps")
print stdout.read(),stderr.read()
```

The problem here is I have to run `watch` or any infinitely running command for 10 seconds and after that I should send `SIGINT`(Ctrl + c) and print the status.

How do I do that?

Comment: One option would be to open another session and run `kill`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get around this would be to open your own session, pseudo-terminal, and then read in a non-blocking fashion, using `recv_ready()` to know when to read. After 10 seconds, you send `^C` (0x03) to terminate the running process and then close the session. Since you're closing the session anyway, sending `^C` is optional, but it may be useful if you want to keep the session alive and run commands multiple times.

```py
import paramiko
import time
import sys

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, port=Port, username=usr,password=Psw)

transport = ssh.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.setblocking(0) # Set to non-blocking mode
session.get_pty()
session.invoke_shell()

# Send command
session.send('watch -n1 ps\n')

# Loop for 10 seconds
start = time.time()    
while time.time() - start < 10:
  if session.recv_ready():
    data = session.recv(512)

    sys.stdout.write(data)
    sys.stdout.flush() # Flushing is important!

  time.sleep(0.001) # Yield CPU so we don't take up 100% usage...

# After 10 seconds, send ^C and then close
session.send('\x03')
session.close()
print
```

Comment: Why some signals are not taking any effect? I tried all the signals. Only `\0x03`, `\x13`, `\x1a` and `\x1c` have some effect. I especially want to  send `SIGSEGV`. I am sure that these signals are not masked.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenSSH 7.9, there's support for [signal requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4254#section-6.8), so by using private API you can send custom-tailored signal message. Note: support was added in 2018-10-19, about three years after the question was asked.

```py
import os
import sys
import time
from signal import Signals

import paramiko
from paramiko.common import cMSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect(
    hostname=sys.argv[1],
    port=sys.argv[2],
    username=sys.argv[3],
    key_filename=str(sys.argv[4])
)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(
    command=f"tail -f {os.getenv('HOME')}/test.txt",
    bufsize=0,
    get_pty=False
)
channel = stdin.channel
time.sleep(0.5)

message = paramiko.Message()
message.add_byte(cMSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST)
message.add_int(stdin.channel.remote_chanid)
message.add_string("signal")
message.add_boolean(False)
message.add_string(Signals.SIGTERM.name[3:])
channel.transport._send_user_message(message)  # angry pylint noises

while not channel.exit_status_ready():
    time.sleep(0.1)

print(f"{channel.exit_status=}")
print("stdout:")
print(stdout.read())
print()
print("channel.stderr:")
print(stderr.read())
```

Output:

```
> python3 test_ssh_sigterm.py localhost 2222 $USER keyfile
channel.exit_status=-1
stdout:
b'some string\nsome other string\n'

channel.stderr:
b''
```

Compare with `resize_pty()` source

```py
    def resize_pty(self, width=80, height=24, width_pixels=0, height_pixels=0):
        """
        Docstring was there.
        """
        m = Message()
        m.add_byte(cMSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST)
        m.add_int(self.remote_chanid)
        m.add_string("window-change")
        m.add_boolean(False)
        m.add_int(width)
        m.add_int(height)
        m.add_int(width_pixels)
        m.add_int(height_pixels)
        self.transport._send_user_message(m)
```

If you have a question why there is no `send_singal` in the code, well, here's [PR from 2019](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1535) (not mine). It's on [Next feature release](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/milestone/25) milestone now, hopefully it will be there this year.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to transport signals is via `terminal`, from `ssh` **man**:

> ```
>   -t   Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
>        arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
>        very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
>        options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
> ```

For `paramiko` check: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/channel.html

> get_pty(*args, **kwds)
>
> ```
> Request a pseudo-terminal from the server. This is usually used right after creating a client channel, to ask the server to provide
> ```
>
> some basic terminal semantics for a shell invoked with invoke_shell.
>   It isn’t necessary (or desirable) to call this method if you’re going
>   to exectue a single command with exec_command.

Comment: That's not true. OpenSSH client requires pseudo-tty so that the control sequences are parsed, but that does **not** necessarily mean that there is no facility to send signals without that. See [RFC4254 (SSH protocol), section 6.9](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-6.9). It does say anywhere that you need a pseudo terminal allocated for this functionality to work..