# How to terminate a remote linux process from Windows 10?

Tags: linux, shell, windows-10, command-prompt

I am running a batch job (run.bat) from my Windows 10.
This process is calling my_program.py:

```
start "my_program" python my_program.py
```

Then my_program.py is calling some script using ssh, let's say:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('12.13.14.15', username="abc", password="cde")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("./load_gif")
```

My (a bit naive) question is:
Is it possible to terminate the remote process by simply closing a cmd window in Windows? If yes - how? Let's say - when window closes I want to send a kill to the remote process or something like `killall python`.

A workaround would be to create another batch that kills the processes. Any other ideas (without knowing the PID) than passing `killall python` in another job?

Thanks, Michal

Comment: You are talking about remote and Linux, I don't see anything of that. Do you use ssh or something else to connect to the other machine?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add what my_program.py does - yes, it connects via ssh to some linux machine. I edited the post and added a piece of code.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910308/how-to-send-control-signals-using-paramiko-in-python